# TensorFlow doesn't work in Atom

Tags: linux, tensorflow, atom-editor

I'm using TensorFlow with Julia, but I can't use TensorFlow with my IDE Atom because it crash Julia.

The problem does not come from TensorFlow because it works in the terminal...

---

Here is the code that makes the editor crash:

```
julia> ENV["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0"  # To use my GPU
"0"

julia> using TensorFlow

julia> sess = Session()
```

The exit error is the following:

```
signal (11): Erreur de segmentation
while loading no file, in expression starting on line 0
unknown function (ip: 0x7f33aa7aec7f)
emit_invoke at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/codegen.cpp:3400 [inlined]
emit_expr at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/codegen.cpp:4135
emit_function at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/codegen.cpp:6101
jl_compile_linfo at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/codegen.cpp:1256
emit_invoke at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/codegen.cpp:3400 [inlined]
emit_expr at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/codegen.cpp:4135
emit_assignment at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/codegen.cpp:3759 [inlined]
emit_expr at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/codegen.cpp:4159
emit_stmtpos at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/codegen.cpp:4064 [inlined]
emit_function at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/codegen.cpp:6248
jl_compile_linfo at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/codegen.cpp:1256
jl_compile_for_dispatch at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/gf.c:1668
jl_compile_method_internal at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/julia_internal.h:307 [inlined]
jl_call_method_internal at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/julia_internal.h:354 [inlined]
jl_apply_generic at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/gf.c:1926
#call#45 at /home/jabou/.julia/v0.6/TensorFlow/src/core.jl:569
unknown function (ip: 0x7f33880acf21)
jl_call_fptr_internal at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/julia_internal.h:339 [inlined]
jl_call_method_internal at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/julia_internal.h:358 [inlined]
jl_apply_generic at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/gf.c:1926
Type at /home/jabou/.julia/v0.6/TensorFlow/src/core.jl:563
jl_call_fptr_internal at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/julia_internal.h:339 [inlined]
jl_call_method_internal at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/julia_internal.h:358 [inlined]
jl_apply_generic at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/gf.c:1926
do_call at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/interpreter.c:75
eval at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/interpreter.c:242
eval_body at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/interpreter.c:543
jl_interpret_toplevel_thunk at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/interpreter.c:692
jl_toplevel_eval_flex at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/toplevel.c:592
jl_toplevel_eval_in at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/builtins.c:496
eval at ./boot.jl:235
unknown function (ip: 0x7f33a6bf0d2f)
jl_call_fptr_internal at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/julia_internal.h:339 [inlined]
jl_call_method_internal at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/julia_internal.h:358 [inlined]
jl_apply_generic at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/gf.c:1926
eval at ./boot.jl:234
unknown function (ip: 0x7f33a6d31a0b)
jl_call_fptr_internal at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/julia_internal.h:339 [inlined]
jl_call_method_internal at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/julia_internal.h:358 [inlined]
jl_apply_generic at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/gf.c:1926
do_call at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/interpreter.c:75
eval at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/interpreter.c:242
eval_body at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/interpreter.c:543
jl_interpret_toplevel_thunk at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/interpreter.c:692
jl_toplevel_eval_flex at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/toplevel.c:592
jl_toplevel_eval_in at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/builtins.c:496
macro expansion at /home/jabou/.julia/v0.6/Atom/src/repl.jl:118 [inlined]
anonymous at ./<missing> (unknown line)
jl_call_fptr_internal at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/julia_internal.h:339 [inlined]
jl_call_method_internal at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/julia_internal.h:358 [inlined]
jl_toplevel_eval_flex at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/toplevel.c:589
jl_toplevel_eval_in at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/builtins.c:496
eval at ./boot.jl:235
unknown function (ip: 0x7f33a6bf0d2f)
jl_call_fptr_internal at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/julia_internal.h:339 [inlined]
jl_call_method_internal at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/julia_internal.h:358 [inlined]
jl_apply_generic at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/gf.c:1926
eval_user_input at ./REPL.jl:66
unknown function (ip: 0x7f33a6c7218f)
jl_call_fptr_internal at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/julia_internal.h:339 [inlined]
jl_call_method_internal at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/julia_internal.h:358 [inlined]
jl_apply_generic at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/gf.c:1926
macro expansion at ./REPL.jl:97 [inlined]
#1 at ./event.jl:73
unknown function (ip: 0x7f338803f50f)
jl_call_fptr_internal at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/julia_internal.h:339 [inlined]
jl_call_method_internal at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/julia_internal.h:358 [inlined]
jl_apply_generic at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/gf.c:1926
jl_apply at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/julia.h:1424 [inlined]
start_task at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/task.c:267
unknown function (ip: 0xffffffffffffffff)
Allocations: 16440349 (Pool: 16435720; Big: 4629); GC: 37

Julia has exited. Press Enter to start a new session.
```

Thank you for your help...

**EDIT**

It works now, I just copied on my desk, then deleted the TensorFlow package from Julia. After I copied the package from my desk to Julia (I didn't change it)...

Comment: Can you check for us if you have a problem with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` envvar as reported in this issue? https://github.com/malmaud/TensorFlow.jl/issues/94

Comment: How to check that, please ?

Comment: Maybe you can printing `ENV["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"]`

Comment: and compare with the one in your bash (`echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`)

Comment: It does not work in Atom: ERROR: UndefVarError: @LD_LIBRARY_PATH_str not defined                                                 // and in my bash, there is nothing returned